# How do i POST to WordPress rest API from the same domain?

Tags: rest-api, 404-error, get-posts, json

I created a custom rest API route - >  `http://mydomain/wp-json/v1/wp/custom/user` now this POST request to this route works perfectly from a remote host.

Some things change in my dev env and the JS files need to be hosted locally and my request no longer work and is now returning  xhr.js:178 POST  http://mydomain/wp-json/v1/wp/custom/user 404 (Not Found) .

How do should I configure my POST request to work inside my WordPress site?

Thank  you,

Comment: Is that the endpoint you're using? Or just an example? I would avoid using the `wp` namespace, and I'd keep the version in the same place core puts it, e.g. `wp-json/wp/v2/posts`. Otherwise, can we see the code that makes the request? If anything I would expect you to be having the opposite problem.

Comment: Wow, this was driving me insane... The correct route, that i setup was  http://mydomain/wp-json/wp/v1/custom/user  not http://mydomain/wp-json/v1/wp/custom/user .... @_@ uhhh, thank for the help. Not sure how I didn't see that before.